# have a number of child level div wrap in a fixed height parent div

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I have a parent div of height 100 px but full width (default).
Inside it I have a lot of 20px by 20px divs.
When the child divs are about to reach the bottom, I want the next ones to start wrapping.
That is, they should start displaying alongside to the right.
In other words I don't want scrolling to happen. But wrapping.

```
<div id="parent" style="height:100px">
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   <div style="height:20px;width:20px"></div>
   ............
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I know if you `float: left;` the children, they'll line up horizontally and wrap to the next line if there are too many. Not sure how to do it the other way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 columns - http://jsfiddle.net/spbqh/

```
#parent {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;

    background: #eee;
}

div > div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: beige;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zoltan for your comment. I have upvoted it as this could have been a solution if they worked on my very specific browser (IE8 with Google Chrome frame). I see that they do work in other latest version of browsers so your answer should help others. I would be open to any suggestions without using CSS3 though as that's what I am looking for.

Comment: In that case I think your only solution is to use wrappers - http://jsfiddle.net/spbqh/1/ that will work down to IE6

Comment: @Vishal -- if you're open to using javascript, this might work:  http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/

Comment: Second solution posted by Zoltan doesn't seem to work on my IE8+chrome frame browser. Deflect, thanks for the js solution.. I am not allowed to use js here though

Comment: @VishalKumar it should work, good sir :) IE8 just doesn't know about the new HTML5 `<section>` element - you might want to replace it with a `<div>`. Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/spbqh/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CSS3 columns.  Unfortunately, they only work on Firefox and Chrome for now, I believe, so it doesn't work in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf5Ma/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="test">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>

        <!-- Snip -->

        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and the CSS:

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
    height:110px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#test{
    height:100%;

    -webkit-column-width:25px;
       -moz-column-width:25px;
            column-width:25px;    

    -webkit-column-gap:0px;
       -moz-column-gap:0px;
            column-gap:0px;
}
.child{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**EDIT**:
I found a javascript-based [column script](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) that could work.  It looks like you just add the javascript after your stylesheets, and you can go ahead and use the new column properties without having to make any modifications.  I've verified it works in IE 9, at the very least.